# creating positive definite matrix using wishrnd in matlab

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, matlab

I used the below code to create a matrix of wishart distribution,

```
clc
sigma =eye(100); df=2;mu=zeros(100,1);
wishart_matrix=wishart_distribution(sigma,df)
normal_vector=mvnrnd(mu,inv(w1),1);

function W=wishart_distribution(sigma,df)
W = wishrnd(sigma,df);
end

function G = gauss_distribution(mu, sigma,count)
 rng default  % For reproducibility
 G = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,count);
end
```

I encountered the below error, it seems `inv(sigma)` is not positive semi-definite matrix, how can i fix it?

```
Error using mvnrnd (line 110)
SIGMA must be a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix.

Error in sahar_vbssm>gauss_distribution (line 323)
G = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,count);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. The function `gauss_distribution` is never called, yet that's supposedly the function that produced the error. Please edit your question provide the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a random positive definite matrix in MATLAB, use

```
a = rand(3,3)
ata = a'*a
```

Comment: i wanna to create a normal-wishart distribution, i cannot use your code

Comment: i wanna to create a normal wishart distribution with parameters $\mu , \lambda , \Sigma , df$, i can not use your code.

Comment: @sahar you can use my code to create the random positive definite matrix `sigma` you were asking about. The rest would work the way it is now.